# Why does adding overflow hide :after and how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, overflow, pseudo-class

When adding an `overflow`-property to the tooltip the `:after`-element vanishes. Why? Is there a fix?

CSS:

```
.tooltip:after {
    border: 4px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0px 0px black;

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<br>
<br>
<div class="tooltip">Without scroll</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="tooltip scroll">With scroll</div>
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcbdjg86/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because overflow is actually still hidden with the `overflow: scroll` properties. The only fix I can come up with is to nest your scrolling div:

```css
.tooltip::after {
    border: 4px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0px 0px black;

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    width: 0px; height: 0px;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.tooltip {
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
}
.scroll > * {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div class="tooltip">
    <div>Without scroll</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="tooltip scroll">
    <div>With scroll</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `:after` in the css is actually outside it's parent element, so overflow will hide it with any value that cuts the content

By pulling things about in order to have the `:after` overlap the edge of the element and achieve the pointer effect it has to breach the boundaries of it's parent, which are what is controlled by `overflow: scroll;` (overflow is still hidden with scroll).

It appears to disappear completely because it is designed  so the bits of it that are inside the parent are invisible. See this [jsfiddle edit that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/tcbdjg86/8/)

You can see in the chrome inspector that it's still there - open up the div and find the after, you can hover on it and see it is there, highlighted.

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems to work when with `position: fixed` insetad of `absolute` on the `tooltip`-class http://jsfiddle.net/tcbdjg86/9/